# Unexpected increase of memory usage on datetime index when using pandas.to_numeric with apply()

Tags: python, pandas

I followed the example from the docs to downcast datatypes to decrease memory usage:
https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/scale.html#use-efficient-datatypes

I tried to downcast two columns of a dataframe with a datetime index from `float64` to `float32` with `pd.to_numeric`.

Given the following dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd # version: 1.3.5
import numpy as np # version: 1.21.5
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.uniform(50, 100, size=(200, 2)), columns=['x','y'],
                                    index=pd.date_range("2022-01-01", periods=200, freq="H"))
```

Data types and memory usage:

```
print(df.dtypes)
x    float64 
y    float64 
dtype: object

print(df.index.dtype)
datetime64[ns]

print(df.memory_usage(deep=True))
Index    1600
x        1600
y        1600
dtype: int64
```

If I downcast the columns `x` and `y` like this, it works as expected:

```
df['x'] = pd.to_numeric(df['x'], downcast='float')
df['y'] = pd.to_numeric(df['y'], downcast='float')
```

Data types / memory usage:

```
print(df.dtypes)
x    float32
y    float32
dtype: object

print(df.memory_usage(deep=True))
Index    1600
x         800
y         800
dtype: int64
```

If I use the `apply()` method to downcast the two columns (also used in the doc example), it also works:

```
df[['x','y']] = df[['x','y']].apply(pd.to_numeric, downcast='float')
```

Data types:

```
print(df.dtypes)
x    float32
y    float32
dtype: object
```

But look at the memory usage of the datetime index. It's over 6 times larger:

```
print(df.memory_usage(deep=True))
Index    9896
x         800
y         800
dtype: int64
```

Why does it behave like this? Did I miss something?

Comment: thank you for your efforts at providing a [mcve], but I cannot replicate this behavior. If I do `df[['x','y']] = df[['x','y']].apply(pd.to_numeric, downcast='float')` I get the expected 1600, 800, 800 memory usage

Comment: So, in the case where you get `9896` for the index, can you give us `.shape` and `dtypes`? particularly `df.index.dtype`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: `df.index.dtype` is still `datetime64[ns]`; `df.shape` is `(200, 2)`

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a bug in older pandas versions (btw, same on Windows and Ubuntu). I just installed pandas `1.5.1` and it works as expected. Unfortunately, I can't update the pandas version in my project yet, so I won't use the `apply()` method until I'm ready to use a newer version.

Anyway, thanks to juanpa.arrivillaga for looking at this.